# How do I use preferredMaxLayoutWidth as automatic for my UILabel and find out the height of its view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios8

In iOS 8 you can seemingly set `UILabel`s to have a preferredMaxLayoutWidth of automatic, which just figures it out via Auto Layout. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to calculate the height of the view the label is inside of. Basically I have a multi-line `UILabel` pinned to the sides of a `UIView`, and I want to know how tall the `UIView` is. (In this case it is a cell.)

If I write:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.label1.text = "some sample text to test it out, and it resolves to two lines long"
    let height = cell.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height

    return height + 1.0 // Extra 1.0 is for separator height
}
```

The height of the cell is always what it would be if the `UILabel` was only one line long. I have `numberOfLines` set to 0, so it should be returning a higher number for the multi-line nature. The `systemLayoutFittingSize` call is clearly not working here.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to get the height of the UILabel and with that value set the cell's height?

Comment: @YuviGr Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always reside on Autolayout by setting the content hugging priority to a value more than the height constraint priority. Or you can use the following code to calculate the height that fits.

```
CGSize sizeThatFits = [YourString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(yourDesiredWidth,MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]} context:nil].size;
```

Edit: 
You have constraints priorities. That means each constraint has a priority in case of conflicts. A higher priority means it will be satisfied first. You just need to set a priority to your content hugging higher than your normal heigh constraint.

[image]

Comment: That second option seems counterintuitive to Auto Layout. Could you explain the first one a little more?

Comment: Hmm, how are you sure that's my issue? I have those values from your screenshot set on my label but the issue remains. Is there anyway you could attach a project showing this in action?

Comment: Those are the default values. Be my guest to change them.

Comment: To a value higher than your height's constraint value. Sadly, I'm not around my Mac to get you a sample code.